# Functions in Node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can define a module in node.js:
**mymodule.js**

```
exports.bar = "Hello";
exports.foo = function(){
    console.log(exports.bar);
}
```

I can require the module:
**app.js**

```
var baz = require("./mymodule.js");
baz.foo(); //Logs "Hello" in the console
```

If I call the `foo` function as above, it logs `"Hello"` in the console. However, the variable that `foo` is logging is `exports.bar`, not `baz.bar`. Does Node.js automatically know to switch them or the `exports` object still exists?

Comment: how and where are you calling them ? Add that part in question too

Comment: I added them! Thanks

Comment: @AndersonIvanWitzke That's where my question is. How does node.js know we're logging baz.bar instead of exports.bar??

Comment: @Caleb How do you know that `foo` is logging `exports.bar` or `baz.bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports` is a special object which is included in every `JS` file in the `Node.js` application by default.

So anything you export in a file (`mymodule.js` in your case) is a property on this object and when you `require` this module `export` object is assigned to the requiring object (`baz` in your case).

When you do

```
var baz = require("./mymodule.js");
```

Your `baz` variable now looks like something

```
baz = {
    bar : "Hello",
    foo : () => {
        console.log(baz.bar)
     }
}
```

And when you call `baz.foo()` you see `"Hello"` printed

Answer (score 0):

When you use exports in the module, This will add property to the object and will use it as just like local object(variable).